# Citation inside amsthm definition causing compilation problems

Tags: citing, theorems, amsthm

## Directory contents

These are the contents of my directory:

```
.
├── bibliography.bib
├── Makefile
└── template.tex
```

I outline the contents of each file below.

### `bibliography.bib`

```
@misc{
  formal_language_proofwiki,
  title={{Definition:Formal_Language - ProofWiki}},
  author={{ProofWiki}},
  howpublished={\href{https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Formal_Language}{link}},
  journal={{ProofWiki}},
  year={2021}
}
```

### `Makefile`

```
compile_pdf:
        latexmk -pdflatex template.tex
clean:
         find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "*.tex" ! -name "*.pdf" ! -name "*.bib" ! -name "Makefile" -delete
spellcheck:
         aspell --mode=tex -c template.tex
```

### `template.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
%first argument to \newtheorem is the environment name which the author would like to use for this element. The second argument is the heading text.
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}
  \begin{definition}[{\cite{formal_language_proofwiki}}]
    A formal language is a structure $\mathcal L$ which comprises of the following:
  \end{definition}
\clearpage
\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}

\end{document}
```

## Problem

In `template.tex` on line 11 I have a citation inside the `definition` environment. This should be possible as per  page 3 of the `amsthm` [docs](https://mirror.lyrahosting.com/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf). However, when I attempt to compile using `make compile_pdf`, the compilation fails:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `formal_language_proofwiki' on page 1 undefined on inpu
t line 11.

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./template.bbl
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.5 \newblock {Definition:Formal_
                                 Language - ProofWiki}.
?
```

Why does this occur and how can I fix it?

Comment: The problem is not the citation but rather the underscore in the title.

Comment: The underscore works fine when I cite outside of the `definition` environment...

Comment: @campa You are correct. Why is it that underscores are OK in the bibtex key but not the title?

Comment: In normal text `_` is reserved for subscripts in math mode. citations and label/ref takes special care to support `_`